# how tu use redux toolkit with nextjs > 10

Tags: redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

I need a link to a tutorial to integrate redux toolkit with nextjs 10.

is it possible ? I know it's possible with nextjs < 10 but getInitialPropos was deprecated.

Thx !

Comment: Here is an [example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux)

Comment: thax for your response ! but is it working with nextjs 10 ?

Comment: it seems to... I'm a newbie. Not sure i understand all things I do/you say :-P sorry for my question

Comment: Works with [latest](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-redux/package.json#L10)

Comment: ok i thought it was not up to date => new to dev.

Comment: thanks a lot ! i start to understand

Comment: The example works with [getStaticProps](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-redux/pages/ssg.js#L9) and [getServersideProps](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-redux/pages/ssr.js#L11)